# Jupyter not importing module files unless imported using "from ... import ..."

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a project organised like

```
project
    proj.ipynb
    blah
        __init__.py
        file1.py
        file2.py
```

inside proj.ipynb I have some code which gives me this output

```
from os import getcwd
print(getcwd()

import blah
print (dir(blah))

from blah import file1
print(dir(blah))
```

>

```
## the correct cwd
['__builtins__', ..., '__spec__']
['__builtins__', ..., '__spec__', 'file1']
```

why can't I just import blah? The same program runs from command line just fine, and the kernal is the same executable of python, so I can't imagine why it has this behavior.

(I'm running on Anaconda 3.6.0 if that makes a difference)

Comment: Importing a package doesn't automatically load its submodules.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise that, so I guess my question doesn't reflect my actual problem. If I replace `blah` with a core module (e.g. `code`) then it will import the core module in python instead of the local namespace (no matter what `sys.path` is), but an imported module (e.g. `numpy`) will correctly import the local version. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't pick package names the standard library has dibs on.